# How can I change the name of a dynamic assembly after it has been created?

Tags: .net, reflection, dynamic-assemblies

Is there any way to change the name of a dynamic assembly after it has been created? I'm using a framework that uses dynamic methods, and it is creating a dynamic assembly with the same name as my main assembly (which causes problems with WPF when it tries to load resources). So I need to find a workaround, and I thought of trying to change the name of the dynamic assembly.

I've tried using GetName() and then setting the Name property, but it appears that GetName returns a clone of the name because my change doesn't stick.

What else can I try?

Comment: Do you have access to the framework source code? Is changing that an option?

Comment: I can't change it directly. I have contacted the developers, and hopefully they will make the change for me.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) to modify the saved assembly and change the stored Assembly Name.